# Multi-part identifier error in SQL SERVER using UPDATE

Tags: sql-server

I am having this error :

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "minus.groupby" could not be bound.
```

whenever I try using this code:

```
UPDATE chadothercharges
SET jan = (SELECT Jan from chadothercharges WHERE chadothercharges.groupby = minus.groupby)
FROM CHADothercharges
```

Chadothercharges and Minus are both TABLE

```
Chadothercharges table column:

acctcode | acctdesc  |  type  |  orderby  |   groupby | Jan


Minus table column:

groupby | MIN | MAX
```

Comment: Is it actual query? You have no any `minus` alias (or table) in it - this is the reason for error to be thrown.

Comment: Regardless of definition of minus and Chadothercharges tables you've provided in update to your question - note that you're **not using** that `minus` table in your query (in joins or applys), so you can't use `minus.groupby`. Probably it's better to describe what your query is supposed to do and provide some sample data these tables contains.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look the definition of minus table, definitely there will not be groupby column.

After watching table structure query will be like :

```
UPDATE chadothercharges SET jan = (SELECT Jan 
                                  from chadothercharges INNER JOIN 
                                  Minus ON Minus.groupby = chadothercharges.groupby)
```

Comment: there is a groupby column in it.

Comment: After watching definition of your tables I will say you can write the query as this : **UPDATE chadothercharges
SET jan = (SELECT Jan from chadothercharges INNER JOIN Minus ON Minus.groupby = chadothercharges.groupby)
FROM CHADothercharges**